# USB Dongle not working if it's connected by default to my Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, serial, uart

I have a USB Dongle That I communicate with it using UART commands.

So if I connect my dongle after starting the system I can send commands and I'm able to receive info, But if I leave the dongle connected to my card and I reboot I receive nothing after command sent and the dongle blocked.

1 Example (works):

1. Start the system
2. connect the dongle after system started
3. send UART command (info\n\r for example)
4. I receive my info correctly

   lsusb:

   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

2 Example (issue):

1. I leave my dongle connected to my Raspberry
2. I reboot
3. I send UART command
4. Nothing happened and the dongle still blocked I can do nothing

   lsusb:

   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80922/discussion-on-question-by-amine-harbaoui-usb-dongle-not-working-if-its-connecte).

Comment: yes you're right, we focused on the problem and we forgot about it

Comment: No big deal -- that's an automated thing.  The system pings a moderator when a certain number of comments are reached and I can opt to move them to chat and leave the canned message.  Keeps things tidy and if you really are chatting that much, you might as well use chat ;)